# VMWare no sound

Tags: audio, vmware, alsa, debian-buster

I have Debian Buster amd64 installed as guest in VMWare Fusion on Big Sur host. My problem is, I do not get any sound.

Sound output in principal should work (I also have a Win7 guest with working sound). However, not so in the Debian guest.

Any ideas where to start?

---

`aplay -l` gives:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: AudioPCI [Ensoniq AudioPCI], device 0: ES1371/1 [ES1371 DAC2/ADC]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: AudioPCI [Ensoniq AudioPCI], device 1: ES1371/2 [ES1371 DAC1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci` shows:

```
...
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller: Ensoniq ES1371/ES1373 / Creative Labs CT2518 (rev 02)
...
```

`lsmod | grep snd` outputs the expected:

```
...
snd_ens1371            32768  1
...
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable Sound in the Virtual Machine settings? It may not have been enabled by default.

Comment: yes, it is enabled and connected

Comment: Must be some issue in the guest machine. I am not sure what. My Ubuntu and Kali machines both have sound via the Windows 10 audio device. I will see if I can see anything.

Comment: There are a couple of things to try (not all the same ) in this VMware thread:  http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=144157

Comment: thanks for the hint, unfortunately, nothing worked. Maybe a bug in VMware or Debian